# execute function only once within other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following function:

```
div_paper.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var mouseCoords = getCoords(event);
    startX = mouseCoords.x - offset[0];
    startY = mouseCoords.y - offset[1];
    rect = paper.rect(startX, startY, 0, 0);
    document.onmousemove = doDraw;
    // the function below i would like to fire once
    rect.drag(drag_move, drag_start, drag_up);
};
```

which fires, as you can see, on every mousedown. I would like to fire the `drag` function only once, after the first mousedown. Should I use jQuery `.one()` for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set a flag `fired = false` and then once the function is called once set the flag to true.

Comment: jQuery .one() should work fine for your purpose

Comment: Only once every time the event occurs, or once period?

Comment: once period! means after the first mousedown it should never fire again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is off the cuff, but you could try:

```
var dragged = false;
div_paper.onmousedown = function(event) {
    var mouseCoords = getCoords(event);
    startX = mouseCoords.x - offset[0];
    startY = mouseCoords.y - offset[1];
    rect = paper.rect(startX, startY, 0, 0);
    document.onmousemove = doDraw;
    // the function below i would like to fire once
    if (!dragged)
    {
       dragged = true;
       rect.drag(drag_move, drag_start, drag_up);
    }
};
```

Comment: works flawless, don't know why i did not think about that. But is it better to use `true` or `false` instead of, lets say strings or numbers? is it better to calculate and you need less debugging?

Comment: @supersize If you're only looking for a "yes" or "no" value (which makes sense here, hence the use of `true`/`false`), then booleans are the way to go. That's kind of their purpose :).

Comment: then again one question, because i would not like to make a new post for that. When i want to "`unbind`" the `mousedown`, despite at which time. i could write `div_paper.onmousedown = null;` right? Its that kind of problem only knowing jQuery and not purely JS.

Comment: Event handlers attached with .bind() can be removed with .unbind(). (As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements.) In the simplest case, with no arguments, .unbind() removes all handlers attached to the elements:

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

So...
div_paper.off('mousedown')

Comment: The boolean data type (true and false) is always the best choice for yes/no operations.